# Wrapping domain classes to ItemViewModel

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

I have a domain class

```
class UserItem(var simpleItem: Item, var id: String, var status: String, var price: Int) {
    var upperLimit: Int = 0
    var lowerLimit: Int = 0
    /* methods here */
}
```

and a class storing these objects

```
class Trades {
    val saleableItems: ArrayList<UserItem> = ArrayList()
    val soldAwaitingItems: ArrayList<UserItem> = ArrayList()

    /* methods */
}
```

`saleableItems` and `soldAwaitingItems` are updated from within `Trades`

I want to display `saleableItems` using `TableView` so that I could bind data and View without converting properties to TornadoFX properties so I wrapped `UserItem` to `ItemViewModel`

```
class UserItemModel(uItem: UserItem) : ItemViewModel<UserItem>() {
    val simpleItem = bind { item?.observable(UserItem::simpleItem) }
    val id = bind { item?.observable(UserItem::id) }
    val status = bind { item?.observable(UserItem::status) }
    val price = bind { item?.observable(UserItem::price) }
    val upperLimit = bind { item?.observable(UserItem::upperLimit) }
    val lowerLimit = bind { item?.observable(UserItem::lowerLimit) }

    init {
        item = uItem
    }
}
```

Is there any way to wrap `Trades` to `ItemViewModel<Trades>` so that I have something like

```
class TradesModel : ItemViewModel<Trades>() {
    val saleableItems: ObservableList<UserItemModel>
    val soldAwaitingItems: ObservableList<UserItemModel>
}
```

and then use it in `View`

```
class TradesView : View("My View") {
val tradesModel: TradesModel by inject()

    tableview(tradesModel.saleableItems) {
        column("Name", UserItemModel::simpleItem)
        column("Price", UserItemModel::price)
        column("Lower limit", UserItemModel::lowerLimit)
        column("Upper limit", UserItemModel::upperLimit)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
class UserItemModel(uItem: UserItem) : ItemViewModel<UserItem>() {
    // Same way you defined previously.
}

class TradesViewModel {
    val saleableItems: SimpleListProperty<UserItemModel>(FXCollections.observableArrayList())
    val soldAwaitingItems: SimpleListProperty<UserItemModel>(FXCollections.observableArrayList())
}

class TradesView : View("My View") {
    val tradesModel: TradesViewModel by inject()

    init {
        with(root) {
            tableview(tradesModel.saleableItems) {
                column("Name", UserItemModel::simpleItem)
                column("Price", UserItemModel::price)
                column("Lower limit", UserItemModel::lowerLimit)
                column("Upper limit", UserItemModel::upperLimit)
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Also, if your table is read-only, you might be able to define `UserItemModel` as a simple data class - no need for extending `ItemViewModel` or performing property bindings.